# Installing Glibc with some additional CFLAGS

Tags: installation, makefile, glibc

I am trying to install a secondary glibc on my machine. As its "INSTALL" file says, the following steps must suffice:

```
mkdir glibc-build
cd glibc-build
../glibc-2.19/configure --prefix=/path/to/glibc-build
make
make install
```

I actually do not have any problem with the simple installation, however, I do not know how I should add my desired CFLAGS to the whole process. I have tried "make CFLAGS=-da" instead of simple "make", however, it returns me errors. I have tried with other options too. Errors appear again. 
Another way was to modify the "config.make" inside the glibc-build. It did not work neither. So, I would appreciate it if you could share your experience in this regard.

P.S.: My desired options are: -da -dv -S

Comment: What errors did you get when you tried the various ways?

Comment: /usr/bin/ld:/home/Yu/Desktop/glibctest/glibcbuild/csu/init.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script

Comment: And what file format does that file have?

Comment: You mean the format of init.o?? object code (application/x-object)!!

Comment: What gave you that output? file(1)?

Comment: Running "make" with modified "config.make" generated that error. I particularly appended "-da -dv -S" to the end of line "CFLAGS = -g -O2".

Comment: That gave you the 'linker script' error? Ok. What told you the file format of `init.o`? Was it `file(1)` or something else? If something else what does `file init.o` say?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here is the output of file init.o :      csu/init.o: ASCII assembler program text

Comment: I'm a bit out of my depth here but that seems like what I would expect to get from `-S`. Are you expecting to get a working library using those flags? What are you expecting those flags to do for you?

Comment: Getting assembly and control-flow graph in RTL format for every .c file.

Comment: That seems like what `-da` and `-dv` do (if I read the docs correctly) but `-S`? Clearly the normal build can't work if you tell gcc to stop early.

Comment: I use -S to dump the assembly in a separate file with .s extension.

Comment: I get the same error even without -S switch.

Comment: If you clean up and then try the build again without `-S` it still doesn't work? Are you supposed to be able to use `-da` and `-dv` during normal compilation this way?

Comment: yep, the same error appears. By the way, I also tried by setting environment variable by exporting CFLAGS="-da -dv" and did "./configure" and "make" steps from the beginning. I get another error this time.

Comment: Here is the error: glibc-build/config.h:4:3: #error "glibc cannot be compiled without optimization"

Comment: That error seems clear enough. You can't remove the `-O` flag entirely. Exporting `CFLAGS=-g -O2 -da -dv` will probably take you back to the other error.

Comment: I did not remove any CFLAGS from the Makefiles. I just set the environment variable CFLAGS. So, you think that it may interfere with optimizations like -Ox?

Comment: I just added a -O2 to the exporting statement and it seems working now. I am waiting for it to finish and hope that I still get the CFGs.

Comment: It works only for -dv -da, if I add -S it does not work even at ./configure step.

Comment: What "does not work" at the "./configure step"? Like I said, I can't see how `-S` is going to work during a normal compilation since it stops the normal compilation flow early (i.e. before producing the normally desired output).

Comment: I see the error: readelf error not an elf file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start

Comment: if -S stops the compilation, what is your suggestion to dump the assembly code? except -g and objdump

Comment: Don't do it during what is supposed to be a normal compilation run which needs the normal output. Use `-S` when you ask the build system to stop at the object file stage.

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanna compile glibc with your desired CFLAGS, you need to include -Ox to the set of flags you are passing as the CFLAGS environment variable.